# SQL ORDER BY "IF"

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-order-by

I want to order by title if column doesn't contain number and by title*1 if its first letter is a number.

```
ORDER BY if(title REGEXP '^[0-9]+'=0,title,title*1) ASC
```

What is false there ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are you sure that *1 does what you think it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which do you want first?  The numbers or the letters?

The problem with your approach is types.  So, decide which one you want first . . . say numbers:

```
order by (title REGEXP '^[0-9]+') DESC,  -- put numbers first
         title + 0,                      -- order by numbers as numbers
         title                           -- order by everything else
```

Comment: order by title+0, title  -- this works fine in my example thanks a lot )))

Comment: @Vesla . . . That can also work, but it puts the non-numbers first.